# Chain slipping off from singlespeed rear cog

Tags: drivetrain, fixed-gear, single-speed

After I have worn out the cogs and chain to the point where my chain tensioner couldn't keep up anymore, I have replaced my drive train pieces, the axle and spacer are still the same.

So I went from:

- [unidentified front wide/narrow chain ring (42T)](https://i.miomoto.de/OBkZHoa.jpg)
- [Gusset 1-er converter 15T](https://www.gussetcomponents.com/shop/hubs-and-cassettes/1-er-converter-12-13t/)
- [SRAM PC-830 (114 Links, 8speed, 3/32")](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/cn-830-a1)

to:

- [absoluteBLACK CX Round wide/narrow chain ring (42T)](https://absoluteblack.cc/cx-rings.html)
- [Shimano CS-MX66 3/32" sprocket 14T](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/dxr-mx70/CS-MX66.html)
- [Connex 8SX Chain](https://www.connexchain.com/en/product/connex-8sx.html)

I switched from 15T to 14T, there is the usual winter surface grime on it (and cleaned up twice already) and switched the chain/sprocket combination because the Gusset conversion kit seemed a bit too wide for being on spec.

That said, ever since I changed parts my chain keeps slipping off the rear cog and already brought me twice into dangerous situations. I've looked around and tried to eliminate the causes, the chain is straight, the spacers on the conversion kit are just like they always have been, the pieces should individually fit. The new chain is a around half the weight of the SRAM chain.

Pictures:

- 1st Bolting, 2nd Tensioner, 3rd spacers, dashing is the freehub (approx):
  [image: https://i.miomoto.de/5Kbwndv.jpg]
- Order of elements: 
  [image: https://i.miomoto.de/BXP4c8A.jpg]
- Closeup: [image: pic]
- level clamped to chainring to ensure the chain is straight: [image: pic]
- axle picture when I initially bought the bike with the original parts: [image: pic]
- picture with chain installed: [image: pic]

Comment: Frozen link in the chain?

Comment: Is the chain tensioner in good condition?

Comment: yes, mint. The old chain tensioner (https://www.gussetcomponents.com/shop/chains-and-chain-devices/2-tugs-chain-tensioners/) had worn out threading and replaced them.

Comment: Did you remove links from the new chain to match the number of links of the old one?

Comment: A "frozen link" is a situation where two adjacent links do not swivel freely.

Comment: I have shortened the chain to have the same link count as the old one which fit everything well.

Comment: @DanielRHicks oh, I was not aware of that terminology. All links move freely and bend 180deg (around the finger) with almost no force (remaining weight of chain)

Comment: Is the chain tight enough? With a smaller rear cog, the chain may need to be a link shorter.

Comment: the tensioner  still has about 1-2mm to go before reaching the maximum length. So tension is good,  it's between tight and very tight to the point where turning (slowly) is a bit audible crunchy.

Comment: Any unusual feel in the pedals before the chain slips off? Also, is there any play in any of the components (rear cog, freehub, rear wheel, chainring/crank, etc)?

Comment: Is the front chainring "true" -- doesn't wobble as it turns?  And is there any play in the crank spindle?  And are there any bent teeth on the front chainring?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by turning the pedals with your hands having the bike in a stand, or upside down? Does it only happen when riding, under load?

Comment: After the chain slips and you put it back on, does it still have good tension, or it becomes noticeably slacker?

Comment: Does the chain actually slip off? Is it possible that the freehub mechanism is failing under force, causing a sensation that feels like the chain skipping? Usually the chain actually coming off the cog with this kind of setup is physically impossible, especially with the kind of freehub spacers you have.

Comment: If the drive train is new, and there isn't a terrible amount of slack in the chain, the only thing that might cause this is the alignment of the ring to the cog. Even a small shift in the gear alignment can make the chain derail. Is it more prone to happen when you are cranking hard? Look down the top of the chain from the ring back to the cog, and try to determine if there could be a slight misalignment. I couldn't tell from the one pic that sort of shows that view, but that might be it.You might just need a spacer on one side of the cog.

Comment: @NathanKnutson as I have put on the chain back on the cog I am certain that it slips. Has happened more of to the right than to the left.

Comment: @RobertLee there is no play to the components, everything is very snug. The chain to be as tense as I'd expected it to be after putting it back on.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I am certain that the chainring is not true and will slowly adjust it. There is at least some play in the tightness of the chain.

Comment: @bradly I have clamped the level on the front chainring multiple times and it is lining up as expected. Measuring it out reveals that the front chainring sits at an inner distance of 45mm, the axle is 135mm with the cog sitting at 22-23mm from dropout to the inner side, making it also about 45mm.

Comment: For the general questions: It only has happened whenever putting work onto the pedals and as far as I can recall on more shaky undergrounds (like cobble stone or general bad ground quality). I have taken a second picture of the lever - it may look like the chainring is bent out of shape but I have verified that it's straight and not bent at any point: https://i.miomoto.de/Rdpwk1O.jpg

Comment: What do you mean "the chainring is not true"?

Comment: I meant saying "The chainring is not center", sorry. @DanielRHicks

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your converter is tight enough?

Comment: @bradly Define "tight". The chain is tight.

Comment: Well, if the chain jumps of this cog, then you've either got a bent tooth on the cog, or the slack part of the chain has made a tremendous lateral movement. Much more lateral movement than seems possible from your second to last picture. So that's two things to check: Are all teeth of the cog straight and true? And is there any possibility of the chain-tensioner to fail under load?

Comment: Interesting ideas - the cog is true. The chain has a slightly more noticeable lateral movement. The tensioner cannot fail under load (at least in itself) due how it screws onto the dropouts and how robust it is built. I have centered the chainring better and increased tension (as well as clean everything up). Testing lateral movement showed also how little play was necessary to allow a misaligned cog. I'll drive that for a while and see if it helped.

Comment: Remember please - answers go in answers.

Comment: I was referring to your single speed converter, is the lock ring tightened to the proper spec?

Comment: @bradly Shimano Freehubs do not need (or have) such a lockring. The cog is a singular cassette cog that is held in place by the geometry of the inner hole. The casette lockring is tight.

Comment: Yes, actually, Shimano cassettes require a lock ring. Your Gusset conversion kit is also secured to the free hub with a lock ring, which is pictured in the image you supplied a link to. There is probably a specified torque suggested by Gusset on how tight that ring should be. If not tightened properly it could seem tight but your cog could still tilt slightly under load and the chain could come off.

Answer (score 1):

Campag toolboxes used to have a tool, looked like a satin chromed steel bar, that was to be placed on the right side of the BB and swung to the left inside of the right frame end. If it didn't just brush nicely, the stays were out of whack. Triple check your BB/cog alignment. All need to be in plane. An aligned chain wheel can't ship the chain off an aligned cog. Determine plane.